# PHP Errors, Boolean Logic

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
require("db_vars.php");

  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password);


  // Custom function to draw a bar graph given a data set, maximum value, and image filename
  function draw_bar_graph($width, $height, $data, $max_value, $filename) {
    // Create the empty graph image
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    // Set a white background with black text and gray graphics

    $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);       // white

    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);     // white

    $bar_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);            // black
    $border_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 192, 192, 192);   // light gray

    // Fill the background
    imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width, $height, $bg_color);

    // Draw the bars
    $bar_width = $width / ((count($data) * 2) + 1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
      imagefilledrectangle($img, ($i * $bar_width * 2) + $bar_width, $height,
        ($i * $bar_width * 2) + ($bar_width * 2), $height - (($height / $max_value) * $data[$i][1]), $bar_color);
      imagestringup($img, 5, ($i * $bar_width * 2) + ($bar_width), $height - 5, $data[$i][0], $text_color);
    }

    // Draw a rectangle around the whole thing
    imagerectangle($img, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $border_color);

    // Draw the range up the left side of the graph
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_value; $i++) {
      imagestring($img, 5, 0, $height - ($i * ($height / $max_value)), $i, $bar_color);
    }

    // Write the graph image to a file
    imagepng($img, $filename, 5);

    imagedestroy($img);
  } // End of draw_bar_graph() function

 // if (mysqli_num_rows($data) != 0) {
    // First grab the user's responses from the response table (JOIN to get the topic and category names)
   $query = "SELECT ts.species_name, COUNT(ti.species_id)  " .
      "FROM tree_species ts " .
      "INNER JOIN tree_individuals ti ON ts.species_id = ti.species_id " .
      "GROUP BY ts.species_name'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $tree_totals = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
      array_push($tree_totals, $row);
    }

        // Generate and display the mismatched category bar graph image
        echo '<h4>Mismatched category breakdown:</h4>';
        draw_bar_graph(480, 240, $tree_totals, 5, 'treetotalgraph.png');
        echo '<img src="treetotalgraph.png" alt="Tree total graph" /><br />';
//}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Generating the following errors

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in G:\Students\test.php on line 54

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in G:\Students\test.php on line 56

Mismatched category breakdown:

Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: Unable to open 'treetotalgraph.png' for writing: Permission denied in G:\Students\test.php on line 43

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in G:\Students\test.php on line 68

Comment: What have you found when you've searched for those error messages?  You *did* search for the errors, right?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear in its meaning.  In order to use mysqli_num_rows(), the first argument passed into it must be a mysqli_result.  What is that?  The result of a database query.  Is what I get when I search for a answer

Comment: Ah, but when you perform a query, things *other* than [statement handles](http://php.net/class.mysqli-stmt) and [results](http://php.net/class.mysqli-result) can be returned.  [`query`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) returns boolean `true` when the query worked but there is no result set, and `false` when there has been an error.  You're going to need to handle this in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what it says: You have not set a timezone explicitly, nor is there one set in the php.ini file.

Add this to the start of your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Comment: Alright, That fixes that time zone errors

Comment: As for the connection ones, check to make sure you're connecting to the correct server with the correct username and password.

Comment: I double checked and the information is correct. Would it have something to do with permissions? I've used the same information in my db_vars.php file below and everything worked.